# Is it possible to make Tabs swipeable in ionic 4?

Tags: angular6, ionic4

I am migrating my application from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4.
Currently I can swipe between my tabs using "swipe" attribute in my  tab

```
swipe($event) {
    if($event.direction == '2'){
      this.navCtrl.parent.select(1);
    }
  }


<div (swipe)="swipe($event)">
...
</div>
```

Knowing that we cannot use "navCtrl.parent.select(1);"
anymore, how is it possible to have swipeable tabs on Ionic 4?